# Extracting the top 10 maximum values in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a value in cell M1 and I need to match it to values in Report! column BE and return the top ten (number of repeating) values from Report! column AY, placed into M24 through M34. I am having difficulty with the formula.

I attempted a formula to bring back the top ten most repeating values that match a criteria. So far I'm using... =IFERROR(MODE(IF(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data,$C$1:C2,0)),Data)),"") to get the top ten reoccurring numbers, then in the next column using =COUNTIF(Data,C2) to show the number of times the number occurs in the range How would I show how many times the number occurs in the range for just one criteria ignoring any blank cells in the range? I' attach an example.

(Below for the new image)

[Top Ten help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gw8S.png)

Comment: What formula have you tried?

Comment: =INDEX(Report!$BA:$BA,MATCH(M1,Report!$BE:$BE&LARGE(Report!$BA:$BA,M21)*57,53)) I tried column BA instead of column AY because it has a numerical value and AY is text

Comment: there are multiple criteria, the value in column Report! BE should match M1 and bring back the top ten repeated values from Report! BA

Comment: Once I get the numerical values I can use a vlookup to add the text

Comment: Don't put question updates in comments. Hard to read and other users won't see it. Edit your question and update it that way.

Comment: I also need to exclude any blank cells

Comment: =INDEX(Report!$AY:$AY,MODE(IF(Report!$BE:$BE='Premier Partners'!$B$1,MATCH(Report!$AY:$AY,Report!$AY:$AY,0))))

Comment: Also returned #VALUE!

Comment: Put Q updates in OP

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into M24 and drag down for an additional 9 rows.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 7, (AY$1:AY$99="abc")*(BE$1:BE$99), ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

btw, M24:M34 is 11 rows not 10.

Comment: How do I have it bring back results that ignore blank cells?

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to use the above AGGREGATE and have it ignore blank cells?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by blank cells. A blank cell is not going to be the Large of anything and a blank cell is not going to be *abc*. In fact, I wrote the above formula to look at rows 1:99 but only filled values in rows 23:55 so there were plenty of blank rows.

Comment: I attempted  a formula to bring back the top ten most repeating values that match a criteria. So far I'm using...

=IFERROR(MODE(IF(1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data,$C$1:C2,0)),Data)),"")

to get the top ten reoccurring numbers, then in the next column using

=COUNTIF(Data,C2) to show the number of times the number occurs in the range

How would I show how many times the number occurs in the range for just one criteria ignoring any blank cells in the range? I' attach an example.